# Is there any possibility to control the iphone's/android's flashlight through as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashlight, air-native-extension

Just that: is there any possibility to control the iPhone's flashlight using any class in ActionScript 3?

Thanks in advance,
DGM.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe you will be able to do this via any ActionScript API.

You will probably have to write an [AIR Native Extension](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html) for this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I have to learn about that a lot, I suppose : )